# Python list comprehension changes initial variable

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I've noticed that when you a run a list comprehension over a pre-existing list, the list is unchanged after the process.

Except, however, if the local names in the comprehension are the same is your initial variable.

Why is this?

Example:

```
>>> y=[1,2,3,4,5]

>>> [X**2 for X in y]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> [y**2 for y in y]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
>>> y
5
```

As you can see, in the second example, `y` has been changed to the integer `5`.

Comment: A list comprehension doesn't introduce a new variable scope.  If you reuse the same variable name, it's going to overwrite that variable with the last value in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in effect rebinding `y` to contain the last value of the original `y`.

It's no different to, say, the following:

```
In [18]: [x for x in range(5)]
Out[18]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [19]: x
Out[19]: 4
```

except that your code uses `y` for two different things, confounding the issue.